# Attendance System SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server

I have tables `Attendance_Employees` and `RFID_User`. Please help me to write this query.

`Attendance_Employees` table:

| Column Name | Data Type |
| --- | --- |
| Name | varchar(100) |
| ID | varchar(50) |
| In_Date | date |
| In_Time | time(0) |
| In_Status | varchar(50) |
| Out_Date | date |
| Out_Time | time(0) |
| Out_Status | varchar(50) |

`RFID_User` table:

| Column Name | Data Type |
| --- | --- |
| Name | varchar(100) |
| ID | varchar(50) |

I want to find today's absent personnel. 3 shift system available (00:00-08:00, 08:00-16:00, 16:00-00:00)

I tried this query for absent people :

```
select 
    d.[In_Date], d.[Out_Date], e.[ID], e.[Name]
from
    (select distinct 
         [In_Date] = convert(date, getdate()),   
         [Out_Date] = convert(date, getdate()) 
     from 
         [personnel_tracking].[dbo].[PAttendance_Employees]) d
cross join 
    [personnel_tracking].[dbo].[RFID_User] e
left join 
    [personnel_tracking].[dbo].[Attendance_Employees a on (a.[In_Date] = d.[In_Date] and a.[ID] = e.[ID]) or (a.[Out_Date] = d.[Out_Date] and a.[ID] = e.[ID] )
where 
    a.[ID] is null
group by 
    d.[In_Date], d.[Out_Date], e.[ID], e.[Name]
```

Result 22 people.

But the correct result would be 29 people - so 7 people are missing (missing shift: 16:00-00:00)

Example timeframe missed by the query:

| Name | ID | In_Date | In_Time | In_Status | Out_Date | Out_Time | Out_Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name | DASDF1545 | 21.07.2023 | 15:55:05 | IN | 22.07.2023 | 00:02:21 | OUT |

Comment: isn't that example says that they logged in **yesterday** and just out **today**? can't you cater for that one particular case?

Comment: My base is weak as I haven't taken a course on mssql. This query is complicated for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this example can help

```
DECLARE @Today DATE = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE());
DECLARE @Shift1Start TIME = '00:00:00';
DECLARE @Shift1End TIME = '08:00:00';
DECLARE @Shift2Start TIME = '08:00:00';
DECLARE @Shift2End TIME = '16:00:00';
DECLARE @Shift3Start TIME = '16:00:00';
DECLARE @Shift3End TIME = '23:59:59';

SELECT
    e.[ID],
    e.[Name],
    @Today AS [In_Date],
    NULL AS [Out_Date]
FROM
    [personnel_tracking].[dbo].[RFID_User] e
WHERE
    e.[ID] NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            a.[ID]
        FROM
            [personnel_tracking].[dbo].[Attendance_Employees] a
        WHERE
            (a.[In_Date] = @Today AND a.[In_Time] BETWEEN @Shift1Start AND 
@Shift2End)
            OR
            (a.[Out_Date] = @Today AND ((a.[Out_Time] BETWEEN @Shift1Start AND 
@Shift2End) OR (a.[Out_Time] >= @Shift3Start)))
    );
```

In this updated query, we added an additional condition to consider the missing shift (16:00-00:00). The subquery now checks for personnel who have not clocked in or out during the first and second shifts (@Shift1Start to @Shift2End) as well as those who have not clocked out after the third shift (@Shift3Start).

This should give you the correct result of 29 absent personnel, including those who missed the third shift.